# What is the best way to find mid points of 1s groups in a python array consist of ones and zeros?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have arrays which contain zeros and ones. I want to find the indexes of middle points of each consecutive 1s groups.
eg:
`array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]`

Then from each consecutive 1s group, the indexes of middle 1s are 
`4 -> from first group`
`10 -> from second group`

What is the best way in python to find these indexes?
(In real scenario these arrays contain around 1000 elements. So I'm looking for a efficient answer)

Comment: What is the middle index of `[1 1 1 1]`?

Comment: @Mr.T the middle index is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numpy solution for improved speed:

```
import numpy as np
array = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]

#padding the array with 0 to ensure that first and last elements are not neglected 
arr = np.asarray([0] + array + [0])
#finding borders between 0 and 1
arr_diff = np.diff(arr)
#finding index values of first and last elements of each group of 1's
first = np.where(arr_diff == 1)[0]
last = np.where(arr_diff == -1)[0] - 1
#calculate the mean value of these indexes
ind = np.ceil(np.mean([first, last], axis=0)).astype(int)
print(ind)
```

Sample output:

```
[ 0  5 12 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply by iterating over list:

```py
def middlePoints(list):
    ones = False
    start = -1
    end = -1
    middle = []
    for index, item in enumerate([0] + list + [0]):
        if item == 1 and not ones:
            ones = True
            start = index - 1
        elif item == 0 and ones:
            ones = False
            end = index - 2
            middle.append((start + end) / 2)
            start = -1
            end = -1
    return middle

print(middlePoints([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0])) # [4.0, 10.0]
print(middlePoints([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])) # [4.0, 9.5]
```

This solution is quite simple, but works in linear time *O(n)*, so I doubt you would find something faster / better.

*Note: here if group of 1s is even, the middle index will be a float e.g. 5.5*

Comment: I'm actually looking for a method with less time complexity because these arrays consist first row values of binary images. So every array contains more than 1000 elements. btw thanks for the answer!

Comment: Unless you know that the density of groups of 1s is low (e.g. a lot are empty spaces - 0s, and only a few 1s), it'll be quite hard to implement some kind of logarithmic complexity search, because in the end, the result will be the same, if not worse

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple algorithm that finds the middle points:

```
array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

def middle_points(array):
    indexes = []
    first_one = -1
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if first_one == -1 and array[i] == 1:
            first_one = i 
        elif first_one > -1 and array[i] == 0:
            indexes.append((first_one+i-1)//2)
            first_one = -1
    if first_one > -1: 
        indexes.append((first_one+len(array)-1)//2)
    return indexes

print(middle_points(array)) #[4, 10]
```

The algorithm has linear complexity with the size of the input, so it is very efficient.